# LINQ - CASE statement in WHERE clause

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm quite new to LINQ. I have a below linq query

```
var entities = context.MessagingTemplateEntities
                      .Where(m => 
                          m.PartyId == partyId && 
                          m.MessageTemplateTypeId == messagingTemplateTypeId &&
                          m.ProductTypePartyId == productTypePartyId);
```

In this query if **productTypePartyId** is 0 then I don't want to include it in **&&** condition. So how can I exclude parameters based on values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why people always force LINQ to be one liners.

```
var entities = context.MessagingTemplateEntities
                      .Where(m => 
                          m.PartyId == partyId && 
                          m.MessageTemplateTypeId == messagingTemplateTypeId);

if(productTypePartyId != 0)
   entities = entites.Where(m.ProductTypePartyId == productTypePartyId);
```

Decide for yourself which is more readable at a glance.

Answer (score 4):

```
var entities = context.MessagingTemplateEntities
                      .Where(m =>
                          m.PartyId == partyId && 
                          m.MessageTemplateTypeId == messagingTemplateTypeId &&
                          (productTypePartyId == 0 ? 
                              true : 
                              m.ProductTypePartyId == productTypePartyId));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `&& (m.ProductTypePartyId == productTypePartyId || productTypePartyId == 0)`
instead of  `&& m.ProductTypePartyId == productTypePartyId`

Comment: this won't work when productTypePartyId is 0, it will be added in AND condition and since there is no record in table with productTypePartyId=0 it will return empty entity.

Comment: Sorry, a typo. Edited my answer - removed `m.` from second clause.